# Using jQuery to make a group of images appear in order

Tags: jquery

I have a page that shows a bunch of thumbnails (around 30), and the client is wanting them to appear one by one, in order, going from left to right on the page. This is what I've tried:

```
var start_opacity = 500;
$j('.grid-photo').each(function(i) {
    start_opacity = start_opacity + 500;            

    setTimeout(function() {
        $j(i).animate({opacity: 1}, 4000);
    }, start_opacity);  
});
```

It doesn't seem to know what i is referencing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) function passes the `index` and the `element` as the arguments of the function.  It also calls the function within the context of the element (`this` points to your element)

You can save a quick variable `var $photo = $j(this);` inside your `.each()` and also, you can calculate your `setTimeout` delay by just taking `500*(i+1)`.  Leaving us with:

```
$j('.grid-photo').each(function(i) {
    var $photo = $j(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $photo.animate({opacity: 1}, 4000);
    }, 500*(i+1));  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/) is a jquery plugin that you can use to achieve your purpose:

Comment: -1 - As much as I love jQuery plugins, this plugin does not solve the OP's problem.  No opacity fades, no "timed revealing", and it would also over complicate the issue, as the solution the OP attempted was only 2 lines of code away from functional.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scope issue.

Try:

```
$j('.grid-photo').each(function(i) {
    start_opacity = start_opacity + 500;            
    var thisImg = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        thisImg.animate({opacity: 1}, 4000);
    }, start_opacity);
});
```